# SSH tunnel without sshd in the middle

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have 3 machines A, B and C. I can ssh from B to A and also from B to C. B will not accept any incoming connections. There is no direct connection between A and C possible.
Is there a way to ssh from A to C and from C to A reusing the ssh connections I created from B?

```
+---+  SSH +---+  SSH  +---+
| A | <--- | B | ----> | C |
+---+      +---+       +---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the existing ssh connections from B are like this:

```
ssh -R 2201:localhost:2202 A
ssh -L 2202:localhost:22 C
```

You can connect from A to C with:

```
ssh localhost -p 2201
```

It is possible to do the same with the `RemoteForward` and `LocalForward` config directives.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!